# Fatal error Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, blob, filesize

this error is driving my crazy and i've been searching the web and haven't been able to solve the problem even though i thought this was a pretty common error. I also found numerous posts addressing that error. Unfortunately nothing worked for me. I'm using a MySQL-Database and created a largeblob field where I want to store images. Everytime I try to upload a picture i get the following error

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 47235072 bytes) in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\Error.class.php on line 173
```

I already changed the upload_max_filesize and post_max_size in php.ini. I also tried adding

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '32M')
```

in various page_setting*.php sites. Nothing worked. I'd be very happy if someone could help me as I'm absolutely out of ideas. Thanks in advance and

Greetings Chris

Comment: Did you try `ini_set("memory_limit","32M");` ?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, No I haven't. Is there a specific file where this is put best?

Comment: You can put this in `wp-config.php`

Comment: I don't have WordPress on the Server yet. If it's needed i will put it up there. But is wp such an essiential part to upload pictures?

Comment: Well, it seems that you used `WP_MEMORY_LIMIT` which will work only with WP sites. You can put `ini_set` in your configure file (or any file which is included in all pages).

Comment: I put it in page_settings.forms.php now. That has an impact. I still get the error. But the allowed memory size changes. What i don't get. It seems he tried to allocate less bytes than allowed but still it wont work

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 104857600 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 35725312 bytes) in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\Error.class.php on line 173

Comment: See my answer, it should works. The error says that script is trying to allocate `~35MB`, which exceeds the limit from `32MB`.

Comment: try using ini_set("memory_limit","-1");

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
ini_set("memory_limit","64M");
```

Probably `32M` is not enough for your script to process the image.

Also, note that `WP_MEMORY_LIMIT` constant will work only if you have Wordpress installed. The setting above is related to PHP itself.

Comment: Still no luck.The size allowed changes up and down when i play with the values but it wont upload. I will install Wordpress now. I'll update if that helped. Thanks alot so far.

Comment: No, installing of Wordpress will not help. When you change the value upto `64M`, what's the error you get?

Comment: Error with 64M
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 24805376 bytes) in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\Error.class.php on line 173
Error with 128M
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 49606656 bytes) in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\Error.class.php on line 173

Comment: Are you trying to upload your image using phpMyAdmin? There's a option in config file called `MemoryLimit`, try to increate this value. Check this: http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html

Comment: Yes, I'm using phpmyadmin to do the initial setup of the database and test some input data. I tried all the options for that value (-1 for no limit was already in there, tried 0 for no changes and '100M' as well). Sadly still no luck